# Prove $\sum_{j=1}^{n}{j\cdot j!} = (n+ 1)!−1$

Tags: number-theory, proof-writing, induction

I got to the point in my proof by induction of (k+1+1)! -1 but I don't know where to go from there.

Comment: Do you mean $\sum_{j=1}^n j\cdot j!=(n+1)!-1$?

Comment: Yes thank you for correcting that I still have issues with my formatting haha

Comment: If yes, then note that $(n!-1)+n\cdot n!=n!(n+1)-1=(n+1)!-1$

Comment: An alternative to induction is to note that the right side counts the number of non-identity permutations of $1,2,\ldots,n+1$. The left side counts the same thing: there are $n\cdot n!$ permutations in which $n+1$ is the largest number moved by the permutation, $(n-1)\cdot(n-1)!$ permutations in which $n$ is the largest number moved by the permutation, and, in general $j\cdot j!$ permutations in which $j+1$ is the largest number moved by the permutation.

Comment: Also note that your expressions both represent the largest $(n+1)$-digit number in the [factorial number system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factorial_number_system).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**: the induction step is just:
$$
(n+1)\cdot(n+1)!+(n+1)!-1=[(n+1)+1]\cdot(n+1)!-1=(n+2)!-1.
$$

Answer (score 0):

you can use this
$$j.j! = (j+1)! - j! $$